# "Apertura" y "abertura". Su uso y etimología

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología

[Abertura](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/index.php?buscar=abertura) y [apertura](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/index.php?buscar=apertura) parecen venir del mismo vocablo latino *apertura*. Tienen significados [diferentes](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/apertura).

Imagino que el proceso fue más o menos como sigue:

- *apertura* se obtiene de la aceptación directa del vocablo latino
- *abertura*, en cambio, parece ser el resultado de convertir el verbo a español (*abrir*), y luego nominalizar.
- ¿Cómo fue la bifurcación de ambos sustantivos?

Algo que me parece interesante, y que quizá pudiera ayudar a encontrar la respuesta, es la evolución de [ambas palabras](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abertura%2F(abertura%2Bapertura)%2Capertura%2F(abertura%2Bapertura)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28abertura%20/%20%28abertura%20%2B%20apertura%29%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28apertura%20/%20%28abertura%20%2B%20apertura%29%29%3B%2Cc0) y la manera en que *apertura* domina sobre *abertura*:

[image]

Comment: Apertura se puede utilizar en contextos como fotografía, ajedrez, fútbol, etc. en la que abertura no se puede. Quizá por eso su uso se ha extendido más.

Comment: chico yo uso abertura como para referirme a un espacio/hueco donde puede salir, entrar o derramarse algo..ej: en la cueva hay una abertura(como un hueco, la otra por ejemplo apertura economica...

Answer (score 2):

A mi parecer, *abertura* se refiere a un orificio, grieta o hueco en una superficie, mientras que *apertura* se refiere a la accion de abrir algo. En algunos contextos *apertura* tiene un significado figurativo; por ejemplo:

```
- Esta tarde se llevara a cabo la apertura de la tienda "X".
```

En este contexto se puede asemejar la apertura con inauguracion.

un ejemplo para abertura:

```
- Se filtraba el agua por medio de una abertura en el techo de la casa.
```

Comment: You say "apertura" twice in your first sentence. I think you want to edit it :)